# USB upgrade to 2.0

Tags: usb, upgrade

**I tried to upgrade USB to 2.0, and I followed instructions from 'Help' step by step.

It says, "look into 'Device Manager - Other Devices' but the problem is, I don't have 'Other Devices' listed there.

Any solution for upgrading to USB 2.0 without 'Other Devices'?**

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by upgrading to USB 2.0?

Comment: And what "help" did you follow ?

Comment: And does that "help" teaches how to upgrade to USB 3.0 :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to "upgrade" to USB 2.0, if you see yellow triangles in Device manager, it means that the device is not installed, so you can go to the manufacturers website (for example [Intel.com](http://www.intel.com)) and download latest drivers.

If however there are no triangles and it is fully installed, you cannot upgrade a USB 1/1.1 socket to 2.0

If you really want USB 2.0, you can get a card that can give you 4 for really cheap (less than £5) if you look online, and possibly cheaper for eBay, won't be a named brand, but nearly all the designs are the same and should get the job done.

Comment: It was taking me too long to transfer data from computer to USB device, so I thought that maybe I have USB 1, so I wanted to upgrade somehow to 2.0, because in the 'Help topics' it is said that it's possible, just to go to 'Other devices' and update driver.

Now I tried another USB device and it works properly (3 min / 715 MB - that's normal, right?), so it seems that I do have USB 2.0 after all, and that the problem was bad USB device... 

Thanks for the answers, I didn't know that it is impossible to upgrade to USB 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

A USB controller, and associated ports can be made according to the USB 1.x, or 2.0 norm. In each case, as long as you use a recent operating system (from Windows XP), drivers for it will be automatically installed.

If your controller (talking about the hardware part) is following the USB 1.x norm, there is no way to upgrade it to USB 2.0, it's linked to the hardware, not to a software or driver upgrade.

More information about USB [version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usb#Version_history) and [history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usb#History) can be found on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usb).